Is it possible to call templated functions in templated derived classes from a pointer to base?
I have a type erased container for holding various classes that meet certain simple requirements. The goal is to provide a consistent interface for similar data-container classes that would then allow users to write and use their own versions as well.
My generic container Elements can intake any class that meets certain properties and pass them around while allowing each instance of Element-acceptable class to use their own implementations of required functions.
Right now, all the supported functionality in the Elements class is for non-templated functions. Is it possible to use a type-erased interface like this to support templated functions as well? Specifically, I want a function to convert between different types classes that are containable by the Elements class.
If my type-erased interface looks something like this:
template <typename T, typename U>
concept HasFoo = requires(T t) {
    { t.foo() } -> std::same_as<int>;
};

template <typename T>
concept IsUserDefinedElements = requires(T) {
    // ... other generic requirement ... //
    requires HasFoo<T>;
};

struct ElementsInnerBase {
    virtual ~ElementsInnerBase() {}
    virtual int foo();
};

template <typename T>
struct ElementsInner final : public ElementsInnerBase {
    // Constructors from T (copy and move variants).
    explicit ElementsInner(const T &x) : _value(x) {}
    explicit ElementsInner(T &&x) : _value(std::move(x)) {}

    // Invoke required methods directly
    int foo() final {
        return _value.foo();
    }

    // Elements object
    T _value;
};

class Elements;

template <typename T>
concept IsGenericallyConstructableElements = requires(T) {
    requires IsUserDefinedElements<T>;
    std::negation<std::is_same<Elements, T>>::value;
};


class Elements {
public:
    // Default constructor
    Elements();

public:
    template <typename T>
    requires(IsGenericallyConstructableElements<T>)
    explicit Elements(T &&x) :
        _ptr(std::make_unique<ElementsInner<T>>(std::forward<T>(x)))
    {}

    // Foo
    int foo() {
        return _ptr->foo();
    }

private:
    // Pointer to the inner base elements
    std::unique_ptr<ElementsInnerBase> _ptr;
};

Individual Element-like class might look something like this.
struct ElementsA {
  int foo();
  // ... A-specific details ... //
};


struct ElementsB {
  int foo();
  // ... B-specific details ... //
};

int run_foo(Elements e) { return e.foo(); }

int main() {
  ElementsA a;
  ElementsB b;

  int aOut = run_foo(a);
  int bOut = run_foo(b);

  return 0;
}

Would it be possible to add some templated function
template <typename T>
T convert();

to the Elements class. Instances of the convert function in each Element-like class might look something like this:
struct ElementsA {
  int foo();
  ElementsB convert() { ElementsB (*this); } // conversion could be arbitrarily complex
};

struct ElementsB {
  int foo();
  ElementsA convert() { ElementsA(*this); }
};


int some_process(Elements e) { 
  // ... generic processes on e ... //

  ElementsB b = e.convert<ElementsB> ();
  // ... B-specific process ... //
}

int main() {

  ElementsA a;
  int aOut = some_process(a);

  return 0;
}

I've seen that the Visitor Pattern can be used to invoke templated functions on derived classes from a pointer to base (similar to this calling a template function of a derived class), but, since the derived class in this instance ElementsInner is templated, I don't see how this could be applied here without directly templating the Elements class, which would defeat the point of the type-erasure.
The type-erasure is important in this context because it allows me to define default behavior for functions users may not want/need to define. And I could just add function wrappers for type-specific function calls, i.e. ElementsB convert_to_b(), etc., but I was hoping to keep the interface clean and generic.

I don't see how your specific design is different from any other design that needs virtual function templates. In any such case the solution is always the same. You need to fix either the set of possible descendant classes (those that override your virtual function) or the set of possible template instantiations, and you need a component that enumerates the fixed set (whatever it is) in one place (not scattered throughout the code). In essence, you give up the openness of either inheritance polymorphism or template polymorphism.

You can't instantiate a template at compile time to match a concrete type that's known only at runtime.  Yet that's what type erasure is for.
